# How to Include promise value in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, bluebird

I am making a small node application with help of `express` and `ejs`.
In one of my controllers I return an object that has a promised property that I would like to include in my view. I was trying to figure out what is the best approach to do this, since it seems `ejs` can't handle promised values. I thought about including the promised value in the model instead, but it seems I overly complicated the code needed to be done.

How can I present a `bluebird` promised value easily in `ejs`?

Controller

```
compaintsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) 
{
    var model = data.complaint.findAndCount({
        include: [data.user, {
            model: data.comment,
            include: [data.user]
        }],
        limit: 15,
        offset: 15 * (req.query.page || 0) 
    }).then(function(result){
        res.render('complaints/list', {model: result.rows});
    });
});
```

`ejs` View template

```
<% model.forEach(function(complaint) { %>

    <div class="complaint">
        ... more html here...
        <footer>
            <span class="vote brand-success">
                <% complaint.votesUp().then(function(votes){%> 
                    <%= votes %> 
                <%}) %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up clickable"></span>
            </span>
        </footer>
        ... more html here...
    </div>

<% }) %>
```

Promised method:

```
votesUp: function() {
    return this.getFollower().then(function(followers){
        var aux = followers
            .selectMany(function(f){return f.UserComplaint})
            .map(function(v){ 
                return ((v.liked === true) ? 1: 0);
            });
        aux.push(0);
        aux.reduce(function(acc, v){
            return acc+v;
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Care to justify your downvote so I can improve my question?

Comment: Does ejs state somewhere in its documentation that it supports promises? Also your `.then` is unnecessary in the template if it did support promises... a promise supporting template would just render `<% complaint.votesUp() %>`

Comment: @Esailija I don't really know how that information may improve my question since I already stated in the question that ejs does not support promises. My code there in the view was my mild temptative to demonstrate my problem and how I tried to approach it, even knowing that promises aren't supported. Would people be kind enough to guide me after showing a bit of effort?

Comment: Because if promises aren't supported it's not possible, so use a templating library that supports promises instead.. nothing more to it. Think how you would implement a templating library with promise support, obviously you need to check if the template creates any promises and wait for them before rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was missing a functionality of my orm, which was sequelize. They allow me to retrieve the association as long as I include the model on my query.
The modifications needed to be done were the following:

Controller

```
compaintsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) 
{
    var model = data.complaint.findAndCount({
        include: [data.user, {
            model: data.comment,
            include: [data.user]
        }, {
            model: data.user,
            as: 'follower'
        }],
        limit: 15,
        offset: 15 * (req.query.page || 0) 
    }).then(function(result){
        res.render('complaints/list', {model: result.rows});
    });
});
```

Method that uses the data:

```
votesUp: function() {
        var aux = this.follower
            .selectMany(function(f){return f.UserComplaint})
            .map(function(v){ 
                return ((v.liked === true) ? 1: 0);
            });
        aux.push(0);
        return aux.reduce(function(acc, v){
            return acc+v;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the answer might be mix business logic into the view so much. Can you get the votes earlier so that you don't have to mess with it in the template? Seems pretty messy. :)

(ps, +1 to offset the downvote)

Comment: The only thing that I might be able to do is perhaps to include the votes in my query and, from there, calculates votes up with the data. I think I was just trying a way to avoid that.